# Need Help sorting out nested for loops

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a trivia game for my English class that will randomly pick a question, but will not pick the same one twice.  I currently have a prototype set up, but I can't figure out what is going wrong that is preventing it from actually printing the questions.
Here's the behemoth:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class qpicker
{
public static void main (String args[])
{
    int qs = 0;
    boolean q1checker, q2checker, q3checker, q4checker, q5checker, 
q6checker, q7checker, q8checker, q9checker, q10checker, q11checker,  
q12checker,q13checker, q14checker, q15checker, q16checker, q17checker,
q18checker, q19checker, q20checker; //this disaster is where i declared my
    q1checker = false;              //booleans
    q2checker = false;
    q3checker = false;
    q4checker = false;
    q5checker = false;
    q6checker = false;
    q7checker = false;
    q8checker = false;
    q9checker = false;
    q10checker = false;
    q1checker = false;
    q12checker = false;
    q13checker = false;
    q14checker = false;
    q15checker = false;
    q16checker = false;
    q17checker = false;
    q18checker = false;
    q19checker = false;
    q20checker = false; //here i tried to set all booleans to false, 
                         //thinking maybe that was the issue
    do
    {

        qs++;
        Random random = new Random();
        double rng = random.nextDouble();
        double selecter = rng * 10;//makes the random number easier to read
        if(rng <=.5)
        {
            if(q1checker = false)
            {
                System.out.println("Put first q in here");
                q1checker = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        System.out.print("cheese");//code progress tracker 
        if(rng <=1 && rng >.5)//this is where the question would be pulled        
        {
            if(q2checker = false)//this ensures questions aren't repeated
            {
                System.out.println("Put second q in here");//display quest.
                q2checker = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        System.out.print("e");
        if(rng <=1.5 && rng > 1)//question picked
        {
            if(q3checker = false)//ensures questions aren't repeated
            {
                System.out.println("Put third q in here");//display quest.
                q3checker = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        System.out.print("y");
        if(rng <=2 && rng > 1.5 )
        {
            if(q4checker = false)
            {
                System.out.println("Put fourth q in here");
                q4checker = true;
                break;
            }
            else if (q4checker = true)
            {continue;}
            System.out.print(" ");
        }if(rng <=2.5 && rng > 2)
        {
            if(q5checker = false)
            {
                System.out.println("Put fifth q in here");
                q5checker = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        System.out.print("good");
        if(rng <=3 && rng > 2.5)
        {
            if(q6checker = false)
            {
                System.out.println("Put sixth q in here");
                q6checker = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        System.out.print("ness");//spells out "cheesey goodness" 20 times
    }while (qs < 20);//ensures all questions are printed (in final product)
}
}
```

Comment: Please learn about arrays and ArrayLists and use them.

Comment: This would be much cleaner with the use of arrays. Make a String array to hold your questions and a boolean array of the same size to record if each was picked or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use arrays.

Also remember that `=` is an assignment operator while `==` is comparation

This:

```
if(rng <=.5)
        {
            if(q1checker = false)
```

Is wrong, it should be:

```
if(rng <=.5)
        {
            if(q1checker == false)
```

Or better:

```
if(rng <=.5)
        {
            if(!q1checker)
```

Comment: Also remember that the `==` comparator is not necessary with boolean as you can simply say `if(!q1checker)`

Answer (score 1):

```
static void shuffleArray(string[] ar)
  {
    //set the seed for the random variable
    Random rnd = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    //go from the last element to the first one.
    for (int i = ar.size()- 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
      //get a random number till the current position and simply swap elements
      int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
      // Simple swap
      int a = ar[index];
      ar[index] = ar[i];
      ar[i] = a;
    }
  }
```

This way you shuffle the entire array and get the values in a random order but NO duplicate at all. Every single element changes position, so that no matter what element (position) you pick, you get a country from a random position. You can return the entire vector, the positions are random.

You could try this method, for shuffling your array and returning the entire array in random order since it mixes the elements.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see you are trying to allow them to choose questions until they are exhausted, choosing randomly. You can do this easily with an ArrayList, where you pick randomly an index from the list to pull your question, remove the question from your list, so it is no longer available to choose from. Note that after you remove and use it from the list, the list will be smaller by 1

```
String[] questionArray = ["Question 1","Question 2","Question 3","Question 4","Question 5"];
ArrayList<String> questionList = Arrays.asList(questionArray);

//Get a random number within the range of 0..questionList.size()
int chosenIndex = 1; //Made up for simplicity
String chosen = questionList.remove(chosenIndex);

//Now that you have chosen a question, and it was removed from the list
//The list is one element smaller. Next time you get a random number
//make sure you use the range: 0..chosen.size()
System.out.println(chosen);
```

I believe this is what you are looking for.